# Re-assign backslash to three dots in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible in Python to re-assign the backslash character to something else, like to the three dots?

I hate the backslash character. It looks ugly.

There’s a long line in my code I really need to use the `\` character. But I’d rather use the `...` character.

I just need a simple yes/no answer. Is it possible? And in the case of yes, tell me how to re-assign that ugly thing.

Comment: Do you mean `\ ` for concatenating statement lines?

Comment: You can avoid using backslash by using parenthesis(According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), avoiding backlash is recommended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not possible but you can follow this,

**According to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)**

> Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions
>   in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a
>   backslash for line continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Python syntactically uses the backslash to represent the escape character, as do other languages such as Java and C. As far as I am aware this cannot be overwritten unless you want to change the language itself.